# Confusion in the derivation of convolution formula

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals, cross-correlation

$$x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)\delta(\tau-t)d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)d\tau$$
Due to linearity,
$$y(t)=T\{x(t)\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)T\{\delta(\tau-t)\}d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)T\{\delta(t-\tau)\}d\tau$$
considering the impulse response of system to be h(t),due to time invariance of unit impulse signal ,
$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(\tau-t)d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau$$
here, i know i have done something wrong, because 

$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(\tau-t)d\tau$
is the formula for cross-correlation between x(t) and h(t)
and
 $y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau$ is the formula for convolution between x(t) and h(t)
but i cannot find, what exactly i have done wrong. could you help?

Comment: correct me, but aren't the last equations of each of your three large formulas totally redundant?

Comment: Could you explain what $T$ is?

Comment: since,cross-correlation and convolution are two separate concepts, they have different formulas. but due to some logical inconsistency, i have arrived at the conclusion that both cross-correlation and convolution have the same formulas

Comment: the last parts are not redundant. look closely, the order of t and tau is interchanged

Comment: ah, so that equality is *wrong*!

Comment: T is just a transformation function that transforms an input to its corresponding output

Comment: but you can't just pull just any function into a single factor of a product of an integrand, even *if* it is linear!

Comment: have a look at page number 6 of this [text](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MITRES_6_007S11_lec04.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion stems from abusing the time invariance property.

Let's restate it for a simple 1D system:

$$ \text{if} ~~ T\{ x(t) \} = y(t) \implies T\{x(t-d) \} = y(t-d) $$ is correct but the following

$$ T\{ x(-t) \} = y(-t) ~~~\text{is wrong in general} $$

Now in your derivation you replace the input $\delta(t-\tau)$ with time reversed input $\delta(\tau-t)$ and claim the same on the output as $h(t-\tau) = h(\tau-t)$ which is not true as shown above.

The solution comes simply by recognizing the fact that $\delta(t-\tau) = \delta(-(t-\tau)) = \delta(\tau-t)$ and then proceed only with the $\delta(t-\tau)$ case as Marcus have stated.